# syntax error in valid if statement

Tags: php

I have a PHP method which retrieves data either from memcache, or from the database if it is not yet available there.
Sometimes the data must be loaded from the DB to update the memcache, for example if something changes.

```
public function get_likes_per_user($u_id, $force_db = false) {
    if ($this->memcache) {
        $u_id = intval($u_id);
        $key = 'liked_news_' . $u_id;
        $res = $this->memcache->get($key);
        if ($res != '') {
            $res = unserialize($res);
        }
        // This line causes a syntax error for no obvious reason
        if(!is_array($res) || $force_db){ 
            $res = array();

            $sql = "...";
            $uu_query = $this->datenbank->query_result($sql);
            while ($row = $uu_query->fetch_row()) {
                $res[] = $row['uu_id'];
            }
            $this->memcache->set($key, serialize($res), 0, 3600);
        }
        return $res;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Kein Memcache Objekt!");
    }
}
```

For some reason I don't understand php decides to throw a syntax error for the if statement which decides whether or not to reload the data from the DB.

I tried different notations for this statement but I can't figure out what causes the error.

Did anyone encounter something similar?

**PHP Version 5.4**

**UPDATE:**

I've found the cause of the error. I am working on a mac and to write a pipe charakter you have to press `alt+7`. If you press `alt+spacebar` mac OS X will insert a non-breaking space, which is invalid for PHP. So my mistake was to keep alt pressed after typing the two pipes for the OR statement.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @JohnConde `unexpected variable $force_db` or `unexpected !` if I switch the parameters

Comment: No syntax error here. Focus on one error at a time.. usually the first one.

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: Maybe you have an unclosed bracket in the earlier code?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes, I know how to debug basic errors in PHP. But in this case none of these were apparend because 1. `$force_db` is set and in scope, 2. there were no missing brackets or semicolons, 3. strings were terminated correctly and 4. the method worked without `$force_db` in that particular if. A coworker with about ten years of PHP experience also had no idea why this was happening. I ended up with a workaround by embedding `$res = $this->memcache->get($key);` into an if that checks `$force_db` and it worked.